# Getting id of randomly generated li in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get id's of `li` via class of `ul` but its not working here is what i am trying

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li id="1234">sheet 1</li>
    <li id="5678">sheet 2</li>
    <li id="11223">sheet 8</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="GetResult();">click</button>
```

here is the JS

```
  function GetResult() {
    var arr = $("myList > div").map(function () {
        return this.id
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        alert(arr[i]);

    }
}
```

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CW3u4/10/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YQ47q/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EKGzY/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing **"."** in selector first of all and inside ul you have li not div, you can iterate all `li` like this

you need only this:

```
    function GetResult() {
    var arr = $("ul.myList li").map(function () {
        return this.id
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        alert(arr[i]);

    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ47q/4/)

Comment: This fixes the selector, but doesn't create the array.

Comment: where OP said the needs an array??

Comment: `var arr =` and the `.map()` method is a pretty heavy clue.

Comment: I just needed to call a function on each id of generated li and this solution worked like a charm .. thanks @ehsan

Comment: if you only need to call function then use ``$.each``, ``map`` is used for returning an array back by some filtering

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
...
<button class="getAll">click</button>
```

and js

```
$(".getAll").click(function() {
    var arr = $(".myList > li").map(function () {
        return this.id
    }).get();
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CW3u4/13/)

Answer (score 0):

it suppose to be `li` not `div`

change this

```
$("myList > div")
```

with

```
$("myList > li")
```